# Make esami balance text in two columns to use all available space on a page

Tags: exam, esami

I am using the esami to create exams, but I have constantly faced a problem which sometimes is hard to solve: esami seems to put each question on a box or similar so if I have, for example, five questions, and they fill nicely a page when written normally (without using esami) but when using esami the text is not balanced in two columns but instead it uses more pages. I normally semi-fix this by playing with the questions ordering and decreasing the font size, which is not ideal. Is there a way to make esami balance text?

The following are minimal examples to show the problem (For instance, I want question 2 to start exactly where question 1 finished):

exam.tex:

```
\documentclass[9pt,letterpaper,spanish]{article}
\usepackage[allowrandomize,shufflerandom,nosolutions,zzz,autopstoff,fillb,sansserif,twocolumns]    {esami}%%%%%pointsonright,solutionsonly,nosolutions,twocolumns,
\usepackage{blindtext}
\def\numcompiti{2}%%% The number of the versions
\date{2016/08/23}%%% THE DATE IN THE FORMAT AAAA/M/D
\begin{document}
\whiledo{\thevers<\numcompiti}{\stepvers
\begin{test}
  \begin{questions}
    \esercizi{question, questionA, questionB, questionC, questionD}
  \end{questions}
\end{test}
\closevers
}
\end{document}
```

question.tex (question{A,B,C,D}.tex are just simlinks to question.tex):

```
\newproblem{
  \blindmathtrue
\item \PTs{0.5} \blindtext[3]
  \begin{answers}{1}\bChoices[random]
    \Ans1 $1$  .\eAns
    \Ans0 $0$  .\eAns
    \eFreeze
    \Ans0 None .\eAns
    \eChoices
  \end{answers}
}
```

and esami-zzz.cfg is just an emtpy file.

Comment: Welcome! I don't know the package, but if it is putting things in boxes, then I don't see there is much you can do without rewriting it to use breakable boxes or to not use boxes.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure if it is actually using boxes or not. It is just an unproven hypothesis.

Comment: Note that `article` does not have a `9pt` option. You'll just get 10pt. Also, I get an error when I try to compile your code `! Package esami Error: La opci\'{o}n zzz no existe.` I don't read Spanish, so I don't know what it says.

Comment: Why don't you remove the `zzz` option if the file is empty anyway? What's the point of making people create an empty `esami-zzz.cfg`?

Comment: It certainly puts problems in `minipage`s`. Whether it puts these particular ones in `minipage`s, I can't figure out.

Comment: The existence of the esami-zzz.cfg is a requirement of the package esami. In this case it is empty just because I created a very minimal example, not because it is not needed. In a complete exam you will put there several definitions and commands needed to configure the exam for the particular needs. I though that just tying touch esami-zzz.cfg would not be a problem ... Thanks anyway for trying.

Comment: You don't need it. If you just delete the `zzz` option, the code compiles fine. It only needs the file if you specify the option.

Comment: Thanks, TIL :) . Still it seems that there is no way to make it balance text ...

Comment: If it is putting it in `minipage`s, no. I can't tell if it is or not. I can tell that it does this with some things sometimes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MCQ exercises have been put in a minipage to prevent them from
splitting on two pages. However, in the xyz.cfg file (the example configuration file that comes with the package on CTAN), circa at line 165
there is a portion of code which begins with

`%%%% %%%%% HERE I GET RID OF THE MINIPAGE IN MULTIPLE CHOICE QUESTIONS`

`%\AtEndOfPackage{
%\renewcommand{\selectrandomly}[1]{%`

and ends with

`%    \ifes@fillin
%     \immediate\closeout\parametri
%     \fi
%}
%}`

If you add this code without comments in your cfg file, you get rid of
the minipage ad columns will be better balanced.

The lines just after the ones I indicated have the
same purpose for open questions (problems).